# DocuSign Webhooks Response - Time Zone

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

We're using the DocuSign SDK (version 3.5.0) We are developing an integration with DocuSign using JWT authentication.

In regional settings of the account, I have set the value of time zone to Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney.

But, whatever the time zone is, in webhooks, the datetime fields are always in UTC. Also, I have noticed that the other APIs such as (audit trail endpoint) also returns the datetime field in UTC.

Will this be constant or this can be changed by any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocuSign's developer support group can update your account's `API Timezone` to a timezone other than UTC. But:

- The `API Timezone` may not work with the newest JSON Connect webhook notification messages.
- If your application is later connected to any additional accounts, then you'd need to have those accounts updated too.

My recommendation is that your software change the timezone for the incoming UTC datetime values. There are library methods for doing this for all languages. (Don't try to write the code by hand, there are some weird corner cases.)